# judging something as poor (objectively) , bad (emotionally)

Tags: selección-de-palabras, adjetivos

In GLU we had a question on difference between *schlimm-schlecht* (*bad-poor*). [My rule of thumb was](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/schlimm-vs-schlecht):

- use *bad* if something feels bad, affects you emotionally in a negative sense
- use *poor* to judge objectively something which doesn't affect you emotionally, e.g., like a teacher judging the grades of a distinct pupil, while the pupil's mother would judge them rather as bad grades from a very personal and emotional point of view, feeling bad about the future of her child.

I'm not looking for spanish adjectives/adverb of *fatal, sick, sad* in English. Doesn't match the the general meaning of *poor & bad* in my opinion. Is there a word matching *malo,mala* for this differentiation in a similar way as in Ger?

Comment: "malo" for bad and "pobre" for poor can also be used in the same way

Comment: @Juanillo that's just how I personally would see the english counterparts of german *schlimm/schlecht*, **while neither of both german adjectives means poor in any way**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot expect 1:1 mapping of words when you translate. Most of the times you'll translate *schlimm* to *malo*, sometimes maybe even *malvado*. In case of *schlecht* your translation will vary. Sometimes it will also be *malo*. In other cases, like for example in case of grading you can say *"notas bajas"*, which I think is used more often than *"notas malas"*.